# Is it need to store all other fields in Solr when using In-Place Updates of single field?

Tags: solr, lucene

I'm trying to add a full-text search feature to project. I don't want to store the full content of all documents, so I decided to use stored="false" for "content" field. Also, there is a boolean field to indicate that a document is deleted or not. When I create a new document in Solr it works great. But when I update is_deleted field - the "content" is appeared to be lost from the index and I can't search this document any more.

I have found [a post](http://lucene.472066.n3.nabble.com/in-place-updates-td4327517.html) that says that fields don't need to be stored when In-Place update, but it doesn't work for me.

**Some details:**

Schema:

```
<field name="id" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true" multiValued="false" />
<field name="_version_" type="plong" indexed="false" stored="false" docValues="true"/>
<field name="is_deleted" type="boolean" indexed="false" stored="false" docValues="true"/>
<field name="content" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="false" multiValued="true"/>
```

Adding a test document using "/update" handler:

```
{
"id": "doc1",
"is_deleted": false,
"content": "SEARCH ME"
}
```

Update document:

```
{
"id": "doc1",
"is_deleted": {"set": true}
}
```

Using Solr v 7.5.0.

Solr [In-Place update documentation](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/7_5/updating-parts-of-documents.html#UpdatingPartsofDocuments-In-PlaceUpdates) doesn't say anything about the need to store all field for this type of update.

Comment: Do you have any copyField instructions? If so, they'll also have to conform to the requirements of inplace updates for it to take place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution. It was my mistake - I considered boolean field as numerical. So that's why In-Place update didn't work for me (because Solr did a common atomic update).

Since I have changed `is_deleted` field from boolean to int everything works correctly and I don't lose data from `content` while updating `is_deleted` anymore.

So the answer is:
**Solr doesn't need to store all field when using In-Place update.**

Thanks to EricLavault for mention field type requirement. It helped a lot)

Comment: Yep... but I was wrong on the main thing !! @MatsLindh Do you know when it came to work with this configuration ? Because when Solr introduced partial updates I'm sure it would not work without storing, I lost enough time with this, Solr was not able to commit a part of a document and all non-updated fields had to be loaded from their *store* (hence my point to the 'update' operation ending in a 'add' op). I wander in which version this feature became effective.

Comment: Yes, but in-place updates isn't the same as partial updates. Regular, atomic partial updates still require all the fields to be set to stored. This is just when all the requirements for a in-place update is there (which is quite more stringent than regular atomic updates, which only require stored to be true), Lucene can update that single value and don't have to re-run all the other fields through the analysis chain. The first version of in-place updates were added in 6.5.

Comment: Ok thank you for the summary. It seems I've never wanted to accept the idea that yes, finally Solr can actually do real in-place updates. I obviously missed something at that time, and since then I've been wrong about that feature... assumptions are evil.